# Kubenet Style Networking in GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I was doing some research on GKE, and was trying to understand the way the pod networking was set up. It surprised me to see that pods received IPs in the GKE cluster's subnet, and that those IPs were addressable from other devices in the VPC.

I was looking at AKS documentation and found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/configure-kubenet

The way IP address reservation works in that article is more aligned with how I expected it to work in GKE. Is there a similar way to set that style of networking in GKE? Where only the nodes have IP addresses on the actual VPC Network, and the pod IP addresses are only addressable from inside the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is [Ip Alias option](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/alias-ip) it will let you assign ranges of internal IP addresses as aliases to a virtual machine's (VM) network interfaces. This is useful if you have multiple services running on a VM and you want to assign each service and pod a different IP address.

You can create two additional secondary CIDR ranges (pods and services) on top of the  primary Subnet for nodes.

[See how to configure](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-alias-ip-ranges).